# Normalization of dictionary values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scikit-learn, normalization

For normalization of elements in numpy arrary, we can use the sklearn normalize function:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

b=np.array([[0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, .30, .24, 0]])
print(type(b))
normalized = normalize(b)
print("Normalized Data = ", normalized)
```

is there any way that I could use the same normalize function from sklearn for the dictionary values?

I have a dictionary like:

```
xy = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.2, 'd': 0.3021651247531982, 'e': 0.24462871026284194}
```

and want to normalize the values of it so that the output could be:

```
xy = {'a': 0.38408524, 'b' : 0.38408524, 'c' : 0.38408524, 'd' : 0.58028582, 'e' : 0.4697913}
```

Comment: @Sandy what type of normalization are you trying to apply?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `Normalizer` function considers the `L-2` norm normalization, but in the following example we will additionally consider `L-1` norm normalization. Taking as example, the array you provided this will be

```
X = np.array([val for val in xy.values()])

# If you're considering norm-1
norm_1 = np.abs(X).sum(axis=0)

# If you're considering norm-2
norm_2 = np.sqrt((X**2).sum(axis=0))


print(f'X with norm 1: {X/norm_1}')
>>> 
X with norm 1: [0.17439926 0.17439926 0.17439926 0.26348688 0.21331533]
print(f'X with norm 2: {X/norm_2}')
>>>
X with norm 2: [0.38408524 0.38408524 0.38408524 0.58028582 0.46979139]
```

Now to directly apply the `L-2` norm to the dictionary we would have to do it manually. In this case, we've already calculated the `norm-1` and `norm-2` values of the array. So it is easy to apply them to the dictionary. Consider the following code

```
# Apply norm-2 to each value in the dict
{key:xy[key]/norm_2 for key in xy.keys()}
>>> {'a': 0.3840852409148149,
 'b': 0.3840852409148149,
 'c': 0.3840852409148149,
 'd': 0.580285823684436,
 'e': 0.4697913855799205}

# Apply norm-1 to each value in the dict
{key:xy[key]/norm_1 for key in xy.keys()}
>>> {'a': 0.17439926331414451,
 'b': 0.17439926331414451,
 'c': 0.17439926331414451,
 'd': 0.26348687578092167,
 'e': 0.21331533427664467}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a numpy array using `dict.items()`. Then apply `normalize` on 2nd column. Finally create dictionary from numpy array.

```
z = np.array(list(xy.items()), dtype=object)
z[:, 1] = normalize(z[:, 1].reshape(1, z.shape[0]))

xy = dict(z)
print(xy)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 0.3840852409148149, 'b': 0.3840852409148149, 'c': 0.3840852409148149, 'd': 0.580285823684436, 'e': 0.4697913855799205}
```